# Why is 称 used instead of 显示 in 消息称，苹果已经开始……?

Tags: word-choice, difference

From a news article [中国市场不能丢！苹果在华销量暴增225%，iPhone12或支持北斗导航](https://www.sohu.com/a/412405103_212351) (10 August 2020), we typically see [显示](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E6%98%BE%E7%A4%BA) meaning "indicate":

> 有统计数据**显示**，……
>
> ……，苹果中国官网介绍**显示**，……
>
> 7月底苹果公布的第三财季的财报**显示**，……

In fact, I've become accustomed to seeing this 显示 sentence structure in news articles in general.  Thus I was a bit surprised by [称](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E7%A7%B0) ("to state") in the following:

> 消息**称**，苹果已经开始对该系列手机的性能进行调试，包括对北斗导航的兼容性和测试。据悉，在此次发布会结束之后，苹果将在官网上明确新机对北斗的支持，以避免受到用户的吐槽。

I feel like there is a difference between 显示 and 称 here, but I don't know what it is.  It's possible it's a grammar point I'm missing, or that there is a technical difference indicating something unverifiable (akin to when English news uses the word "allegedly").

**Question**: Why is 称 used instead of 显示 in the above sentence?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 显示 = indicate

消息显示 - The announcer observes the information that's available and provides a report to the audience

The source of the information may or may not have provided the material directly to the announcer

> 称 = announce/ claim

消息称 - The announcer directly relays the announcement or claim from the source of information to the audience

The source of the information has made the announcement/ claim itself

Also:

证据显示 - evidence indicates (evidence doesn't make claim)

发言人称 - the speaker claims (speaker announces, not indicates an announcement)